# How to include/require external file in to the foreach loop and be able to read the loop's variable?

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to include an external file in the a foreach loop, and be able to read that variable of the foreach loop in that external php file. Please see the code below:

```
$ProductPDSLink = '';

foreach($item->ProductRangeName as $rangeName){

    include($App_URL . '/Handler/_PDSSwitcherHandler.php');

}
```

And in the included external php file the code below:

```
global $rangeName;
global $ProductPDSLink;
switch ($rangeName) {
    case 'Insurance':
        $ProductPDSLink .= "LInk";
        break;
    case 'Priority Protection':
        $ProductPDSLink .= "Link2";
        break;
    case 'Life Solutions':
        $ProductPDSLink .= "Link 3";
        break;
}
```

Finally I try to echo it but nothing showing up.

```
echo $ProductPDSLink;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you edit your post to provide the code where you try to `echo` it?

Comment: why not create a class instead of including the whole file?

Comment: Re - roullie, foreach($item->ProductRangeName as $rangeName) also in another foreach loop.

Comment: This is a horrible design. You should define a function in the include file, include it just once, and then use `$ProductPDSLink .= functionName($rangeName);` in the loop.

Comment: Enable error reporting, and make sure it's successfully including the file. Other than that, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have actually tried that, in the included file I added function PDSLink(); and then include the file in the loop but the error message says 'Call to undefined function PDSLink()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, thanks for tips.

I created a class and function inside the class then parse function to the loop. so the code below:

In the include file:

```
class PDS{
   public static function functionName(){
         global $rangeName;
         global $ProductPDSLink;
         switch ($rangeName) {
        case 'Insurance':
            $ProductPDSLink .= "LInk";
            break;
        case 'Priority Protection':
            $ProductPDSLink .= "Link2";
            break;
        case 'Life Solutions':
            $ProductPDSLink .= "Link 3";
            break;
    }
   }
}
```

then I include the file then parse them in the loop using $PDS = new PDS(); $ProductPDSLink .= functionName($rangeName);

now it works!